# Useful functions with spare NOR

Tags: logic-gates

Assume a circuit has a spare nor gate. Can any useful functions be created by connecting one of the inputs to logical one? To logical zero?

Comment: This question is too vague such that it leaves no room for useful answers. NOR gates are already useful and it just does whatever a NOR gate does. One thing a NOR gate can do is a NOT gate. NOR gates can be used to detect if both inputs are 0 or if at least one input is a 1.

Comment: Assuming you’re talking about a two-input NOR. Tying one of the inputs to logical 1 will always output logical 0. Tying one input to logical 0 or tying the two inputs together will create an inverter. Whether it is useful depends on the circuit which the spare NOR gate is part of, which you have not told us anything about.

Comment: The use is limited only by your imagination and needs for an inverter or gated one.

Answer (score 3):

This reminds me of a question I once got on a final exam:
"Provide five uses for the "nop" instruction".

For a two input NOR gate, let's see...

1. Each input presents about a 5pF load so you can add 5 or 10pF to a net that needs it.
2. The output could be doubled with another NOR doing the same thing to double its current drive capability.
3. The inputs probably have a diode to the rails so with a suitable input resistor could provide a voltage reference of VCC+diode.
4. With a resistor or short between output and and input the output will likely sit at VCC/2, or maybe even oscillate.
5. Apply two white noise sources to inputs (50% probability of 0 and 1), output will have only 25% probability of 1, so that's what, pink noise or something.
6. The NOR will have an output impedance of say 300 ohms, so with both inputs low the output will provide a VCC source with a 300 ohm output impedance without the exorbitant cost of a resistor.
7. Attaching long wires to inputs but otherwise not connected, touching wire with finger may generate 50Hz or 60Hz square wave at output depending on where you are in the world, so serves as a crude GPS.
8. Tie both inputs and output to ground and get a heater.

Comment: A free running oscillator by connecting the output to both of the inputs.